# I tried to find min of binary tree but output is address

Tags: c++, pointers, binary-tree

Update

Thanks for all the answers. I suppose I know the mistake is come from double comparison. It seems numeric_limits does not run well on my computer.I wrote a simple function to compare double and it works:

```
bool compareDouble(double a,double b)
{
if(a-b<-EPSILON) 
    return true;
else
    return false;
 }
```

===============

I tried to write a simple function to find min in a binary tree. The function can run well, but the output is `8106336` which is not a value in the tree, but looks like the address. I do not understand why.

The tree is defined as following, language is c++

```
typedef struct myNode* LPNode;
typedef struct myNode Node;

struct myNode
{
  double key;

  LPNode Left; //left subtree
  LPNode Right; //right subtree
};
```

The function of find min is as following, min is initialed as `99999`

```
double minValue(LPNode Root,double min) {
  if(Root == NULL)
    return min;
  if(Root->key < min)
    min = Root->key;
  min = minValue(Root->Left, min);
  min = minValue(Root->Right, min);
  return min;
}
```

Comment: It could also be uninitialized data.

Comment: How are you printing the output? Can you show a small example of a tree where it goes wrong?

Comment: can it be your tree initialization if not initializing the `key` ? can you post a simple, complete program?

Comment: You need to show us how you get the number 8106336 and how you output it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So ,I have to show the double type version:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <limits>  


    typedef struct myNode* LPNode;
    typedef struct myNode Node;

    struct myNode
    {
        double key;

        LPNode Left; //left subtree
        LPNode Right; //right subtree
    };


    double minValue(LPNode Root,double min) {
        if(Root == NULL)
            return min;
        if(Root->key -  min < std::numeric_limits<double>::min())
            min = Root->key;
        min = minValue(Root->Left, min);
        min = minValue(Root->Right, min);
        return min;
   }

 int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
 {

    LPNode node1 = new Node;
    LPNode node2 = new Node;
    LPNode node3 = new Node;
    LPNode node4 = new Node;
    LPNode node5 = new Node;
    LPNode node6 = new Node;
    LPNode node7 = new Node;

    node1->key = 10.01;
    node2->key = 9.1;
    node3->key = 8.2;
    node4->key = 7.4;
    node5->key = 6.6;
    node6->key = 1.1;
    node7->key = 12.2;

    LPNode root = node1;
    node1->Left = node2;
    node2->Right = node3;
    node2->Left = node4;
    node3->Right  = node5;
    node3->Left = node7;
    node7->Right  = node6;

    double mymin = minValue(root, 99999);

    std::cout << mymin;
    delete node1;
    node1 = NULL;
    delete node2;
    node2 = NULL;
    delete node3;
    node3 = NULL;
    delete node4;
    node4 = NULL;
    delete node5;
    node5 = NULL;
    delete node6;
    node6 = NULL;
    delete node7;
    node7 = NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think using `numeric_limits` better than a MACRO

Comment: Cool. BTW Did you figure out how the OP ever got 8106336?

Comment: @wshcdr Thanks a lot for your code. I suppose my mistake is on double comparison. Although numeric_limits does not run well on my computer, I think I can figure out it soon.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, You can't compare double type using > or < or == ,
I rewrite using int like following:

```
    #include <iostream>

    typedef struct myNode* LPNode; 
    typedef struct myNode Node;

    struct myNode
    {
        int key;

        LPNode Left; //left subtree
        LPNode Right; //right subtree
    };


    int minValue(LPNode Root,int min) {
        if(Root == NULL)
            return min;
        if(Root->key < min)
            min = Root->key;
        min = minValue(Root->Left, min);
        min = minValue(Root->Right, min);
        return min;
    }

    int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
    {

        LPNode node1 = new Node;
        LPNode node2 = new Node;
        LPNode node3 = new Node;
        LPNode node4 = new Node;
        LPNode node5 = new Node;
        LPNode node6 = new Node;
        LPNode node7 = new Node;

        node1->key = 10;
        node2->key = 9;
        node3->key = 8;
        node4->key = 7;
        node5->key = 6;
        node6->key = 1;
        node7->key = 12;

        LPNode root = node1;
        node1->Left = node2;
        node2->Right = node3;
        node2->Left = node4;
        node3->Right  = node5;
        node3->Left = node7;
        node7->Right  = node6;

       int mymin = minValue(root, 9999);

       std::cout << mymin<< std::endl;
       //free node1 ... node7
       delete node1;
       node1 = NULL;
       delete node2;
       node2 = NULL;
       delete node3;
       node3 = NULL;
       delete node4;
       node4 = NULL;
       delete node5;
       node5 = NULL;
       delete node6;
       node6 = NULL;
       delete node7;
       node7 = NULL;
       return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You've still used < surely? And not `delete`d anything you `new`ed.

Comment: you could use correct way to compare double type data, I put codes here to verify the logic is right.